# How accurate are geocoding API's and what is the most accurate?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, bing-maps

I'm creating an application with google maps api with geocoding functionality. Obviously, I want to use the api that is the most accurate. I'm giving the application an address and I need to find it on a map, but I would be ok with just finding the latitude and longitude, and then I can use that to incorporate it into whatever map api I choose. Out of your experience, which api is the most accurate? Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc. And if you could give an approximate percentage that would be great. So far I'm using Google, as it seems to be the most robust, but I would consider changing for more accuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the free services are only going to be accurate to a road segment. For each road segment they store the start and end street numbers, and then interpolate. This saves processing time and disk space, it also adds some resilience against new buildings.
However, it does result in evenly distributed addresses or clumping depending on how the street numbers are allocated in real life. Also side-of-street rules may not be consistent. Hence the free and low cost services are not considered good enough for emergency services and even some urban planning.

You mentioned robustness, a good fix for this is to use multiple APIs. use the most robust first. if that fails, your program can try a different one.

Comment: Didn't know that's how they did it.. makes sense. +1 for interesting info

Comment: You know how it is - you pays your money! High end systems will have inidividual addresses and regular updates on a subscription basis.

Comment: I Agree, very interesting. Thanks for the info. Can you point me to some paid services? This application I'm building does happen to be for the emergency services, so I need as most accuracy as possible. As I have no funding for the project yet I'm using the free sources as a proof of concept and I can always go from there.

Comment: I assume you're in the US? I would try Navteq, TeleAtlas and local government (cities) to see what they have. National Mapping Agencies are a good start (eg. the OS in the UK) but the USGS's map data is old/poor, and I don't think the US Census Bureau sell this information (worth a try but I think they only have it in aggregate form) and their update intervals won't be very often.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the US... in the NY area (just north of NYC). I'll check those out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

USC had a reasonably good geocoder, which they transferred to Texas A&M.
It's supposed to be at "http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/", but it's down.