# Google Maps/Place Geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, geocoding, google-geocoder

Currently I am using Google Maps for both Autocomplete as well as Geocoding function.

However, I realized that Google Maps geocoding is rather inaccurate for most cases and also chanced upon a few links suggesting to use Google Places API.

As the Google Maps method which I have implemented is based on Javascript approach and it does not require any API key. Therefore, it does not have much restriction since it is based on client side limit.

However for Google Places, it seems that it requires an API key and have a different set of usage limit.

Before I convert and explore on Google Places API:

1. May I know is there any better free alternative for geocoding solution which is good/accurate?
2. Is it possible to configure Google Places geocoding in a way similar to Google Maps so that the usage limitation is held at client level?
3. Or is there a strategy that I can try/consider. Example, create a few Google Places account/API key, and develop some logic e.g. (if apikey1 exceed limits, switch to api2 etc..)? Before that, is it able to track or detect the current limit via portal or coding level respectively?

Comment: The geocoder now requires a key as well (at least the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does)

Answer (score 2):

**May I know is there any better free alternative for geocoding solution which is good/accurate?**

I think Google Maps offers the most accurate among free geocoding services. Reading from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159314/how-accurate-are-geocoding-apis-and-what-is-the-most-accurate), if you're really concerened about precision, then consider using paid services.

**Is it possible to configure Google Places geocoding in a way similar to Google Maps so that the usage limitation is held at client level?**

Here's a statement from Google about [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

> The Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1 000
>   requests per 24 hour period, which you can increase free of charge. If
>   your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing. Verify your
>   identity to get up to 150 000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling
>   billing on the Google API Console. A credit card is required for
>   verification. We ask for your credit card purely to validate your
>   identity. Your card will not be charged for use of the Google Places
>   API Web Service.
>
> The limit for free usage is 150 000 requests per 24 hour period. If
>   your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing again. Purchase
>   a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license to get more than 150 000
>   requests per 24 hour period.
>
> Please take steps to increase your limit early if you expect to exceed
>   the default number of requests allowed.

**Is there a strategy that I can try/consider. Example, create a few Google Places account/API key, and develop some logic e.g. (if apikey1 exceed limits, switch to api2 etc..)?**

It seems there is no such feature. If you want to exceed the free quota, consider
 payment.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there are many restrictions on the Google APIs. In fact, in the terms of use, the Google Maps API requires that you use the geocode information with a map presentation—you can't just print the numbers.

And yes, the Google Maps API guesses an approximate location based on the address input. For instance, if you give it a complete address that is not a real place, it will try to give you somewhere in between the real places that would probably be next to it. This is one of the reasons you will often get inaccurate geocode information from them. Overall, the API is great for what it is designed to do.

As someone who works in this industry, I'm not actually aware of any completely free geocoding and autocompleting service. Most products have a free tier though (up to so many uses per week or per month, etc).

(Full disclosure: I'm a developer at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where I work on the US Autocomplete API as well as the US Street Address API, which provides geocoding.)